# ELEMENTOR styling the checkboxes in the form - no setting?

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I am using a number of checkboxes on my Elementor Pro form and I see no setting to style the checkmark nor the box. The CSS  I would assume I would set also doesnt seem to do anything. Anyone else successfully made a form and been able to change the size and color for the check box?

input[type="checkbox"]:checked{color:pink} nor input[type="checkbox"]::after{color:pink}

I am using the default WP theme 2021 and have no other plug ins.

This also makes no difference
[image]

[image]